# How to do inner joins using Kusto query language on AppInsights

Tags: join, azure-data-explorer, kql, appinsights

I'm using the following query to get the operationId values from the requests that failed with 400 using AppInsights:

```
requests 
| project timestamp, id, operation_Name, success, resultCode, duration, operation_Id, cloud_RoleName, invocationId=customDimensions['InvocationId'] 
| where cloud_RoleName =~ 'xxxx' and operation_Name == 'createCase' and resultCode == 400 
| order by timestamp desc
```

I use these operationId values on the following queries to get the logs of what happened:

```
traces
| union exceptions
| where operation_Id == '35edbc7c13f7ac4c85fa0b8071a12b72'
| order by timestamp asc
```

[image]

With this I'm getting the information I want but I need to write and execute queries several times so I'm trying to do a join between both queries without success as I'm not an expert on querying AppInsights and I'm not sure about how to do the join with a union, can you help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try the query below:

```
requests 
| project timestamp, id, operation_Name, success, resultCode, duration, operation_Id, cloud_RoleName, invocationId=customDimensions['InvocationId'] 
| where cloud_RoleName =~ 'xxxx' and operation_Name == 'createCase' and resultCode == 400 
| join (
    traces
    | union exceptions
) on operation_Id
| project-away operation_Id1
| order by timestamp asc
```

More details on the `join` operator - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/joinoperator